# Tracking pixel clicks on a SVG image element with any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, vector-graphics

I'm writing a photo editing server in Node.js. The problem I'm having is when attempting to track the pixel that the user clicks on the image. My implementation was working perfectly on Firefox but when I tested it on Chrome the pixels returned by event.offsetX and event.offsetY are completely different between browsers, which has been a common problem for a long time (at least according to research).

It wouldn't be an issue if the images I'm expecting to work with were not so large. on average about (1000+px x 5000+px) with some images reaching over 20,000px in 1 direction. When i scale it into a div that fits the page, Firefox uses an offset of the parent which is correct but in chrome the px values returned are either bigger than the image or smaller than the image depending on how it has been rendered into the div.

I need a way to reliably track the pixel that the user clicks on the SVG image element that takes scaling into account. I've tried resizing every parent element and I tried calculating the image location based on getBoundingClientRect() but again the value comes out too high or just plain incorrect.

https://jsfiddle.net/ruamz0oe/

HTML

```
<svg id="svgWrapper" class="image-image" viewBox="0 0 2880 1620" style="border:2px black solid;" width="2880" height="1620">
  <image id="crop" width="2880" height="1620" xlink:href="https://d2r55xnwy6nx47.cloudfront.net/uploads/2019/07/Planet-Formation_2880x1620_Lede.jpg"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet" style=" position:relative; " clip-path="url(#image_box)"/>         
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="image_box">
      <rect x="0" y='0' width="100%" height="100%" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs> 
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.image-image {
  display: block;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.image-image:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

svg { position: relative; text-align: center; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("image").on("click", function(event)
  { 
    // In firefox
    if(typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined')
    {
    alert('Image was clicked in FF');
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
      alert("The Pixel clicked was: " + x + ", " + y);
    }
    else
    {
        // some other browser
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
      alert("The Pixel clicked was: " + x + ", " + y);    
     }

  });// end click event
});
```

this is what I'm working with and I've attempted changing the width and height of the svg element but since my images are so large it renders in a very inconvenient way for the user. Running the above code on Firefox works wonderfully but using chrome breaks the pixel locations in pretty obvious way.

I don't receive errors it just gets the wrong location and I've exhausted all my ideas since I'm a bit of a newbie to vector graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!!! Huge thanks to [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-translate-from-dom-to-svg-coordinates-and-back-again/) that described the SVG point mapping system very well and even has an example that helped me on my way.

[This is the cross browser code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvcxkej8/6/)

The key was this function:

```
  // convert client coordinates to svg element coordinates
  function svgPoint(element, x, y) {
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;
    return pt.matrixTransform(element.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  }
```